# Define method in class dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to define a function in a class on the fly depending on arguments given during the object creation. I tried a few ideas (code below) but they are all not valid. Maybe it is not possible. I'd like to do this because I would call the `_exec` method very often in a Monte Carlo simulation.

My first failing idea:

```
class Test_Class_1():
def __init__(self, a = None):
    if a:
        self.a = a

if hasattr(self, 'a'):    #self is undefined.
    def _exec(self):
        print(self.a)
else:
    def _exec():
        print('no a')
```

And my second failing idea:

```
class Test_Class_2():
def __init__(self, a = None):
    if a:
        self.a = a

try self.a:           #this is invalid syntax
    def _exec(self):
        print(self.a)
except:
    def _exec():
        print('no a')
```

I could of course create different classes to achieve this but I'd rather want one class to have an easier comprehensible code structure (much shorter).

Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: please seriously format..

Comment: What do you expect to happen if the instance variable `a` is modified or deleted after the object is created? Do you want it to also update `_exec()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `__setattr__()` method to dynamically update the `_exec()` method depending on the value of attribute `a`. Two different implementations for `_exec()` are provided as methods in the class, and the appropriate one is selected whenever the attribute is modified.

Also override `__delattr__` in case the attribute is deleted using `del`.

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, a=None):
        self.a = a

    def _exec_a(self):
        print(self.a)

    def _exec_no_a(self):
        print('no a')

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
#        print('__setattr__():', name, value)
        super().__setattr__(name, value)
        if name == 'a':
            if value is not None:
                self._exec = self._exec_a
            else:
                del self.a

    def __delattr__(self, name):
#        print('__delattr__():', name)
        super().__delattr__(name)
        if name == 'a':
            self._exec = self._exec_no_a
```

Use it like this:

```
>>> x = TestClass()
>>> x.a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'TestClass' object has no attribute 'a'

>>> x._exec()
no a
>>> x.a = 123
>>> x._exec()
123
>>> x.a = 'hello'
>>> x._exec()
hello

>>> x.a = None
>>> x.a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'TestClass' object has no attribute 'a'
>>> x._exec()
no a
>>> x.a = 500
>>> x._exec()
500
>>> del x.a
>>> x._exec()
no a
>>> x.a = True
>>> x._exec()
True

>>> x = TestClass(a='xyz')
>>> x._exec()
xyz
>>> del x.a
>>> x._exec()
no a
```

Answer (score 1):

One natural way to do this would be:

```
class Test_Class_1():
    def __init__ (self, a=None):
        if a:
            self.my_func = lambda y: y*y

m = Test_Class_1()
m.my_func(100) # raises an error because my_func doesn't exist
v = Test_Class_1(100)
v.my_func(100) # returns 10000
```

---

Your first idea doesn't work because `self` is a local variable, which exists only during the execution of a method. In the execution of the class body, it does not exist.

Comment: Thanks Hori,
that is a very elegant solution. But in my case I need more than a `lambda` function. So I chose mhawke's answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this, just create a helper function in which you set the function using `setattr`:

```
def set_func(self):
    if hasattr(self, 'a'):    #self is undefined.
        def _exec(self):
            print(self.a)
        setattr(type(self), '_exec', _exec)
    else:
        @staticmethod
        def _exec():
            print('no a')
        setattr(type(self), '_exec', _exec)
```

and call it after setting `a` in `__init__`:

```
 def __init__(self, a = None):
    if a:
        self.a = a
    self.set_func()
```

Comment: Hi Jim,
I wasn't able to able you suggestion. Could you show a complete working example and explain it a bit? I think it is similar to mwhake's solution but manages somehow to not call the class (explicitly).